# Using SVN commandline tools via Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm using the Subversion Plug-in for Jenkins, which I read from its description that it "`adds the Subversion support (via SVNKit) to Jenkins`". So far my Jenkins projects can both successfully checkout and update the workspace without issue. However in some of our vcxproj files there are some prebuild steps that query `svn info <directory>` via the command line to get the revision number to insert into some code generated header files that ultimately get consumed by resource files to yield file versions for dlls and exes. My Jenkin's slaves don't have SVN installed to run the native command line application. Is there a means to expose the SVN tools, ie SVNKit, that Jenkins uses to the command shell. My build is configured as an `Execute Windows Batch Command`.

I'm wondering if there's a way to put the svn command from SVNKit on the path for shell commands invoked by Jenkins. To be concrete what would it take to accomplish the following command in the screenshot below without installing svn on the slave machines.

[image: making SVN accessible from command line]

Comment: I think you're out of luck with this approach. I'm not sure there's a way to get access to the SVNKit jar that Jenkins uses on the slave. Jenkins does provide environment variables to the build steps with the revision and URL (unsurprisingly named `SVN_REVISION` and `SVN_URL`). Perhaps you can modify your prebuild steps to use the environment variables instead of running `svn info`.

Comment: I did some testing earlier to see what environment is actually utilized from the batch command, and it appears its that of the slave. Putting the command `ECHO %COMPUTERNAME%` demonstrated that pretty clearly. I'm currently going the route of setting up the environments of all the slaves to have SVN command line client on the path but it would have been desirable to someway have SVNKit/Jenkins do that on my behalf in some way. From %JENKINSHOME% there's the SVNKit jar file under `plugins\subversion\WEB-INF\lib\svnkit-1.8.11.jar` but how to open it up, use the credentials Jenkins uses, tricky